# How do I get windows previews when hovering over icons in the launch bar?

Tags: unity, compiz

Guys I saw a video on the net regarding compiz to enable windows preview option when i hover a mouse over it. That would be similar as in Windows 7.

I installed compiz through Ubuntu Software Centre and then I searched and found that there is no option called "Windows Preview" in it!

There is a unity option but it doesn't have a windows preview option.
Also I would like the freedom to move unity anywhere from top-bottom-left-right.
Will this damage my system?

Please reply at the earliest :-|

Answer (score 6):

You have to install **"CompizConfig Settings Manager"** through Ubuntu Software Center.
[image]

Then launch the  **"CompizConfig Settings Manager"** application and search in "Extras" for the "Windows Previews" plugin and enable it.
[image]

Move your mouse to the unity laucher and the "preview window" should appears.

[image]

Cheers.

Comment: You may need to install the package compiz-plugins for that option to appear.

Comment: When I have more than one instance of the same program open, is it possible to make the preview show all of the instances? Currently it only shows a thumbnail of the most recently viewed instance.